# Test if Excel has finished its startup / shutdown sequence

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, com, excel.application

I'm using `PowerShell` to automate some excel tasks via COM, via a `PowerShell` script like so:

```
$xl = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
sleep 5
DO THINGS...
$xl.quit()
sleep 5
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
[GC]::collect()
```

My issue is that if I omit the first call to `sleep`, Excel won't be ready to perform tasks that require add-ins, and the call to `$xl.quit()` doesn't work, and the process fails to quit, as evidenced by:

```
PS > Get-Process EXCEL

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    784     104   104008     109380   944     3.21   5996 EXCEL
```

Likewise, if I omit the second call to `sleep`, excel doesn't have time to complete shutting down, and eventually this results in a dialog box stating "Microsoft Excel has stopped working..." and the next time Excel starts up, another dialog box states "Microsoft Excel failed to shut down properly, Start in safe mode?"

```
function XLtest {
    $xl = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $xl.quit()
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
    [GC]::collect()
}

for($i=0;$i -lt 10; $i++){ XLtest } # generates multiple errors
```

Obviously these are problems that I want to avoid, but the heuristic solution of calling `sleep 5` could still fail on ocasion. Is there any way to detect when excel has completed it's start-up sequence and is ready to issue commands (`xl.quit()` in particular) and when the shut-down sequence is complete (i.e. when it's ok to call `[System....Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your exact environment and situation is impossible to reproduce without an add-in like the **DO THINGS...** one mentioned, there are members of the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) that should be able to be exploited to gain some sense of the application state.

One that seems a likely candidate is the [_Application.CalculationState property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.calculationstate.aspx). If a full recalculation was forced then a `Do While...: DoEvents: Loop` was processed, a pseudo-timer could be pausing the powershell script while the `Application.CalculationState` was not `xlDone` much the same as an Internet.Explorer object is waited upon until it finishes receiving its web page.

```
$xl = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Calculate
do while $xl.CalculationState <> xlDone: $xl.DoEvents: Loop
$xl.quit()
... (do more things?)
```

A recalulation can also be forced with the [_Application.CalculateBeforeSave property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.calculatebeforesave.aspx) if you are saving before closing (and subsequently exiting).

Another good candidate is the simpler [_Application.Ready property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.ready.aspx).

```
$xl = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
do while not $xl.ready: $xl.DoEvents: Loop
$xl.quit()
```

See [Application Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198091.aspx) for a full list of potential properties where a 'state' can be determined. More information at [Developer’s Guide to the Excel 2010 Application Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192737(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Jeeped!  Liberal use of `do while not $xl.ready: $xl.DoEvents: Loop` (in VB) and/or `while(! $xl.ready){sleep .1}` (in powershell) in excel before and after calls to `open()`,`save()`,`saveas()`,`quit()`, and `Workbooks.Add()` did the trick!